# Weird rendering issue - rendering from Edit mode

Tags: rendering

I have this weird rendering problem.
When I am in object mode I press <kbd>F12</kbd> and I get this:

[image: Weird rim reflections, shifted brake rotor texture]

The rim has strange reflections and artifacts, also the texture of the brake rotor (which is UV based) is shifted (In the viewport the image is correct). It happens only with this object. But if I select it, switch to edit mode and then press <kbd>F12</kbd>, this happens:

[image: Correct one]

As far as I can tell, this render is absolutely correct. It only happens when I select this exact object in edit mode. The only modifier is *Subdivision* (not applied). The appearance of other objects is not changed. This problem is present in Blender 3.1 and 3.4.

Any advise is highly apreciated. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if you have different settings for viewport and render in the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier on the object? Enabled/disabled in one or the other? Different levels of subdivision? And I'm not sure what you mean by saying _"only modifier is Subdivision (not applied)"_ - applying a modifier in Blender means permanently change the mesh and removing the modifier. So you either have the modifier or you applied it and it's gone. Or did you mean enabled instead of applied? Then as mentioned before, check if you have different settings for viewport and render (or even _Edit Mode_).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I meant modifier is enabled but not applied. And, thanks to you, i've found source of that issue: i had subdivision modifier option "Use modifier during render" box unchecked. probably miscklicked at some point